# Java - How to move files using FileUtils?

Tags: java, file, io, move, fileutils

Everyone keeps saying how simple it is to move a file from point a to point b using fileutils, but I'm having lots of trouble moving a file :(

I have a /temp/ folder in the directory wherever the .jar is located, in this temp folder I have a .txt file I want to move up a directory (so basically next to the .jar file) but I cant seem to do it?

Here's some code, but I know its not even close:

```
public void replaceFile() {
    String absolutePath = getPath();
    Path from = Paths.get(absolutePath + "\\temp\\test.txt");
    Path to = Paths.get(absolutePath + "\\test.txt");

    try {
        FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.getFile(from.toAbsolutePath().toString()), FileUtils.getFile(to.toAbsolutePath().toString()));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getPath() {
    File jarDir = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath());
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jarDir.getAbsolutePath());
    return jarDir.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Any help is appreciated :\

Comment: You should add what's the wrong behaviour you've noticed

Comment: the file not being moved

Comment: Had you tried to println the path of the source file before the move?

Comment: yh one of them is /temp/test.txt other one is /test.txt, paths are fine

Comment: i get ioexception

Comment: your application has the rights to move of the file (for example is the owner)?

Comment: yh it should do

Comment: What does the IOException messages say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok i managed to do it, apparently the getPath() method returned some funny path and it failed there, so heres a code that works

```
public void downloadJar() {
    String absolutePath = getPath();
    String from = absolutePath + "\\temp\\test.txt";
    String to = absolutePath + "\\test.txt";
    File fileTo = new File(to);
    File fileFrom = new File(from);


    try {
        FileUtils.moveFile(fileFrom, fileTo);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "io exce");
    }

}

public String getPath() {
    return System.getProperty("user.dir");
}
```

thanks everyone

Answer (score 5):

Why don't use this Java API for [Moving a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html)

`Files.move(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

**UPDATE**

Looking at your source code I suggest the following implementation:

```
Path from = Paths.get(absolutePath, "/temp/test.txt");
Path to = Paths.get(absolutePath, "/test.txt");

try {
    Files.move(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can you give an example where it works? to see where i mess up

Comment: I've updated my answer. I've tried this version locally on my machine, if the source and destination path are correct it works.